# Differential Equation of Arbitrary Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I'm given the following differential equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial z^2}-\frac{1}{u_p^2}\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial t^2}=0$$

and asked the following:

> Show that any function in the form of $F(z-u_pt)+G(z+u_pt)$ will satisfy this differential equation ($F$ and $G$ are arbitrary functions).

Now, I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to take a partial derivative of an arbitrary function. I have some work, and ended up with the right answer, but I'm almost positive that this cannot be correct. Can someone. please point me in the right direction?

My work:

[image]

I realize now as I upload my pictures that choosing a function $U$ was a poor decision. $U_p$ and $U(z,t)$ are not the same (Sorry).

Comment: You are right to be skeptical, since the problem (as stated) is wrong! There is no reason for arbitrary functions to have one, let alone two derivatives. But what you've done correctly is show that *if* $F$ and $G$ both have two derivatives everywhere, then the equality holds.

Comment: Oh, and if you're looking for a keyword, this is [d'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Alembert's_formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations. You have made use of chain rule correctly provided those partial derivatives exist.